# How to calculate average values based on a value change in another column in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, average

I want to average values in a column that are in the same row of a repeating value in another column. So for rows of data, every time the value changes in a column B, the code would average the previous values of another column A for rows where the value repeated in column B before the change occurred.

I have developed quite the process in Excel, but I know there has to be a better way with Python.
Example of data:

```
A,B
1.22E-04,2
1.28E-04,2
1.43E-04,2
1.04E-04,2
1.28E-04,2
2.23E-04,2
1.34E-04,2
1.07E-04,2
7.01E-05,2
6.10E-05,2
1.34E-04,2
3.66E-04,2
1.40E-03,3
2.87E-03,3
5.18E-03,3
5.49E-07,1
6.40E-07,1
6.40E-07,1
7.01E-07,1
7.32E-07,1
6.71E-07,1
6.71E-07,1
8.53E-07,1
1.19E-06,1
5.49E-03,3
6.10E-03,3
8.53E-03,3
1.04E-02,3
1.28E-02,3
4.27E-04,2
1.46E-04,2
7.62E-05,2
5.18E-05,2
6.10E-05,2
2.13E-04,2
1.01E-03,3
1.83E-03,3
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the indexes of the rows where the values change are written to the ind list. This is done by checking if the previous value is equal to the other. [Shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) is used for this.

Next, in the list comprehensions, at each iteration, the my_func function is called, which calculates the average values and sets them through slices of the [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) indexes.
In iloc, these are row indices on the left, column numbers on the right(starting from left to right).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ind = np.array(df[df['B'] != df['B'].shift()].index)

def my_func(x1, x2):
    df.iloc[x1:x2, 0] = df.iloc[x1:x2, 0].mean()


[my_func(ind[i], ind[i+1]) for i in range(len(ind) - 1)]


print(df)
```

Output

```
               A  B
0   1.433417e-04  2
1   1.433417e-04  2
2   1.433417e-04  2
3   1.433417e-04  2
4   1.433417e-04  2
5   1.433417e-04  2
6   1.433417e-04  2
7   1.433417e-04  2
8   1.433417e-04  2
9   1.433417e-04  2
10  1.433417e-04  2
11  1.433417e-04  2
12  3.150000e-03  3
13  3.150000e-03  3
14  3.150000e-03  3
15  7.385556e-07  1
16  7.385556e-07  1
17  7.385556e-07  1
18  7.385556e-07  1
19  7.385556e-07  1
20  7.385556e-07  1
21  7.385556e-07  1
22  7.385556e-07  1
23  7.385556e-07  1
24  8.664000e-03  3
25  8.664000e-03  3
26  8.664000e-03  3
27  8.664000e-03  3
28  8.664000e-03  3
29  1.625000e-04  2
30  1.625000e-04  2
31  1.625000e-04  2
32  1.625000e-04  2
33  1.625000e-04  2
34  1.625000e-04  2
35  1.010000e-03  3
36  1.830000e-03  3
```